# Information about net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I need to know some information about the error  `net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`.

-1- How much time does it take to have this error?

-2- Is it a fixed ammount of time for all browsers or each browser has different?

-3- If each browser has different ammount of time to throw the error how can someone retriave the time ammount information with javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timeout duration depends on which application will deliver you the data or handles the data request e.g. Apache. In most cases, you can set the timeout by your own e.g. for Apache. It can have a range from a few seconds to a few hours.

Found some old defaults for Internet-Explorer:

- Internet Explorer 4.0 and Internet Explorer 4.01 5 minutes
- Internet Explorer 5.x and Internet Explorer 6.x  60 minutes
- Internet Explorer 7 and Internet Explorer 8  60 minutes

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/181050

But all in all, you should be able to set the timeout in your appropriate application.

Comment: Ok i got the answer for 1,2. How about the 3rd? How I get the timeout of my application of javascript or having it set as you propose?

Comment: It really depends on your application. E.g. in Apache you can edit it in the httpd.conf as far as i know. I think there is no way to get this value in your client (like javascript).

Maybe you can messure manually the time between send and recieve data (or recieve the timeout). Maybe some applications offer an interface to get this kind of information, but I don't think so.